# C# Blazor - Static method isn't recognised

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a static method in the form:

```
public static class ValidationHelper
{
    public static StringBuilder BookingKeyInfoValidation(ViewBookingDTO SelectedBooking)
    {
        StringBuilder errMsg = new StringBuilder();
....
```

I then try to use it in a non-static method:

```
StringBuilder errMsg = ValidationHelper.BookingKeyInfoValidation(SelectedBooking);
```

I receive an error stating that

> 'ValidationHelper' does not contain a definition for
> 'BookingKeyInfoValidation'

How should I be calling the Static Method?

Comment: Are you missing a using ? Where is the method called ? @code{) or in html etc. Please provide more information.

Comment: @jeb you put me in the right direction, it was getting confused with the  System webPageUiHelpers.